# curl download works fine but wget fails using ssl

Tags: linux, wget, curl, ssl

When I try to download a file using `curl` command, the file is downloaded successfully:

```sh
curl -O https://domain/file --capath /etc/ssl/certs/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 36.6M  100 36.6M    0     0   826k      0  0:00:45  0:00:45 --:--:-- 4276k
```

When I try to download the same file using `wget`, I get the following error:

```sh
wget -vS --ca-directory=/etc/ssl/certs/ https://domain/file
--2016-11-23 15:36:50--  https://domain/file
Resolving domain... 
Connecting to domain|194.126.106.153|:443... connected.
ERROR: cannot verify domain's certificate, issued by '......':
  Unable to locally verify the issuer's authority.
To connect to domain insecurely, use `--no-check-certificate'.
```

I used the same self-signed certificate in both tests.

Comment: It would probably work if the certificate was signed by a CA (which is then self-signed) which would reside under `/etc/ssl/certs`.

Answer (score 3):

Either specify to not check the CA certificate with `--no-check-certificate` or specify the location of your signing certificate that you signed your self signed cert with using `--ca-certificate=<file>`  or  `--ca-directory=<directory>` to point to a directory containing signing certs in PEM format